# How to make Ease In/Out Back animation constant regardless of movement length

Tags: algorithm, math, calculation, tween, easing

I have three objects moving from position A to position B with an ease-out-back animation. The target positions A/B are different for each object. How can I dynamically calculate the overshoot movement constant for the ease-out-back animation?

The default ease-out-back animation looks like this:

```
           a------->b<-
       a----------->b<--
 a----------------->b<---
```

The arrows after B represent the ease-back animation.
I want to achieve ease-back movement regardless of the length, like this:

```
           a------->b<--
       a----------->b<--
 a----------------->b<--
```

I've tried calculating a constant overshoot value, but without success. I've also attempted to create two separate sequence animations - linear and ease-back, for constant duration I use `abs(end-start)/speed` formula but the animations don't look joined. The ease-back movement always appears faster than the slower linear movement.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired effect would be greatly appreciated.